# splitting an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to split the image names from an array.

```
$this->_filenames[]= array($name);
$files = explode(",", $name);
```

When I do a `var_dump` on `$files` it returns both images stored in the array as shown below:

```
array
    0 => string 'felton300.jpg' (length=13)
1
array
    0 => string 'felton400.jpg' (length=13)
1
```

if I try to store each element (using the code below) in the array using `list()` I get an error.

```
list($img1,$img2) = $files;
```

The error is: `Undefined offset: 1`

I'm uploading the images from a form and want to use the variable (ie $img1) as a reference to insert into a mysql database. Here's my code for uploading the image.

```
public function move($overwrite = false) {
$field = current($this->_uploaded);
if(is_array($field['name'])){
foreach($field['name'] as $number => $filename){
```

//process the multiple upload

```
$this->_renamed = false;
$this->processFile($filename,$field['error'][$number],
$field['size'][$number],
$field['type'][$number],$field['tmp_name'][$number],
$overwrite); 
}
} else  {
$this->processFile($field['name'],$field['error'],
$field['size'],$field['type'],$field['tmp_name'],$overwrite);
}
}

protected function processFile($filename,$error,$size, $type,$tmp_name,$overwrite){
$OK = $this->checkError($filename,$error);
if ($OK) {
$sizeOK = $this->checkSize($filename, $size);
$typeOK = $this->checkType($filename, $type);
if ($sizeOK && $typeOK) {
$name = $this->checkName($filename, $overwrite);

$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $this->_destination . $name); 
if ($success) {
```

//add the amended filename to the array of filenames

```
$this->_filenames[]= array($name);
```

//split the array******THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO SPLIT THE ARRAY SO I CAN STORE THE IMAGES IN A MYSQL TABLE. THE TABLE WILL HAVE 3 COLUMNS id, image1, image2 ***********

```
$files = explode(",", $name);
var_dump($files);
```

Comment: What programming language ? And what sort of a tag is `into` ?

Comment: You should at least tag your posts with language in the future. I'm assuming PHP?

Comment: OK - I've fixed the tags now at least. Please pay more attention when posting questions in future.

Comment: Clear as mud. Muddy mud. You haven't shown us your input, or how you're producing that output, or anything like that. It's also not clear what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two images in an array, why not

```
INSERT INTO table (id, image1, image2) VALUES ({$id}, '{$files[0]}', '{$files[1]}')
```

Why bother splitting them?

And from the looks of this

```
array
    0 => string 'felton300.jpg' (length=13)
1
array
    0 => string 'felton400.jpg' (length=13)
1
```

You have a multidimensional array here (notice each has a key of 0).  It's hard to tell with what you've provided, but

```
INSERT INTO table (id, image1, image2) VALUES ({$id}, '{$files[0][0]}', '{$files[0][1]}')
```

May also be a solution for you.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to php so it isn't always that simple to explain to the wider community what i want. For that I appologise.
Yes, it is a multidimensional array as you pointed out above. I tried your suggestion but it just inserted the string '$files[0][0]' and '$files[0][1]' rather than the actual filenames.

Comment: Try concatinating `mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id, image1, image2) VALUES ({$id}, '" . $files[0][0] . "', '" . $files[0][1] . "')");'

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same result. It just inserted the string not the element.

Comment: Can you post your statement with it's surrounding PHP?